# CSS - repeating background-image should be completely visible

Tags: css, background-image

Is it possible **via CSS** to force the **`background-image` which is repeating** that it should be completely visible (not cut at the end of the container)? The **container-height is flexible**!

[image]

It should look like on the right side but I get a result like on the left side if the content 
grows.

There are two possible ways:

1. avoid the `background-image` to overflow (I can't use `background-size: contain` because it's repeating)
2. force the container to grow gradually

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's wrong on the left side and need to be fixed? Are you just talking about the black bar?

Comment: The dots are cut off on the bottom row

Answer (score 0):

this is not the best solution but maybe it will help: if you can ignore IE8 and below, you can use the [`background-size`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) property, it will allow you adjust the size of the images with percents so they will feet completely to what you need (and will stay in the same position at resize), then you can use the [`background-position`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) property and move the images little bit for a better result. then, when you will try to resize it you will see that it stays in the same ratio on the screen but the images are getting bigger because of the percents, so make sure to upload bigger images from scratch so when the images will get bigger they will not resize above the real image size.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/fq5dkL51/2/

Comment: We get closer to the solution, but the problem is that the size of the background-image should be fix. Imagine if the content grows a lot, the bullets would be very big.

Comment: can you please bring a live example of the issue?